# Load protocol buffer objects into a collection from a file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

If I have a file with many protocol buffers messages saved in one after each other, how do I read that file back to a collection in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How did you delimit the protobuf messages?

If you just wrote them one after the other, without using `writeDelimitedTo` you can't read them back, it's just not a format that protocol buffers support.

If you did use `writeDelimitedTo`, I think you can figure out the corresponding parse method.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to writeDelimitedTo and it works now. is there a single method to load all into a collection?. I can sure write my own parser but thought to ask about it.

Comment: No, but it really is just a two line loop (terminate on `null`).